# Getting SSL issue when run docker-compose up command

Tags: php, docker, ssl, docker-compose, alpine-linux

Configuration of system:

Host OS: Windows 10

WSL 2 distro: Ubuntu 18.04

Docker desktop: 4.22.0

---

I have the project into WSL Ubuntu-18.04 distro at /home/git directory.
There is dockerfile (pasted below).
I have docker desktop on windows, which is connected to WSL 2 Ubuntu-18.04.

Now from Windows OS through Powershell I am trying below docker-compose command:

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\git>docker-compose up

Issue: When I run above command I get the following errors:

-----Errors Start-------------------------------------------------------

```
 => ERROR [app base  2/12] RUN echo @3.8 http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main >> /etc/apk/repositories     && echo @3.8-community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/  1.6s
------
 > [app base  2/12] RUN echo @3.8 http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main >> /etc/apk/repositories     && echo @3.8-community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community >> /etc/apk/repositories     && apk update     && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps         autoconf                 dpkg-dev dpkg           file            g++             gcc         libc-dev                 make            pkgconf                 re2c     && apk add --no-cache         libgcj@3.8         pdftk@3.8-community     && docker-php-ext-install         soap     && apk del .build-deps:
0.405 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.524 488BF75ACB7F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
0.525 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: Permission denied
0.525 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: No such file or directory
0.525 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.580 488BF75ACB7F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
0.581 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: Permission denied
0.581 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: No such file or directory
0.581 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.964 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
1.254 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
1.556 v3.13.12-94-g0551adbecc [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community]
1.556 v3.8.5-67-gf94de196ca [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main]
1.556 v3.8.5-66-gccbd6a8ae7 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community]
1.556 2 errors; 18830 distinct packages available
```

I found temporary solution from Internet which I added below line top of the DockerFile.

Temporary solution line -

```
RUN sed -i 's/https/http/' /etc/apk/repositories
```

When I inserted the above line, the errors mentioned above vanished. Because basically I moved all HTTPS to HTTP urls just for Alpine directory. But since it was just for specific repo related fix, the DockerFile could not run completely successfully and received below errors frequently:

New error:

```
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

And DockerFile keeps executed infinitely due above recursive error.

---

From those errors I have learned about there is SSL related issue. But I do not know exactly how to rectify this.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

---------DockerFile-------------------------------------

```
# RUN sed -i 's/https/http/' /etc/apk/repositories

# install system packages
RUN echo @3.8 http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo @3.8-community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community >> /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        libgcj@3.8 \
        pdftk@3.8-community \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        soap \
    && apk del .build-deps

# install custom nginx
COPY ./.docker/app/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY ./.docker/app/nginx/security.conf /etc/nginx/

USER www-data
COPY .docker/app/entrypoint.sh /home/www-data/entrypoint.sh
COPY .docker/app/modules/ /home/www-data/modules/
COPY .docker/app/run-dev.sh /home/www-data/run-dev.sh
COPY .docker/app/run-prod.sh /home/www-data/run-prod.sh

USER root
RUN chmod +x /home/www-data/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod -R +x /home/www-data/modules/
RUN chmod +x /home/www-data/run-dev.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/www-data/run-prod.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/www-data/entrypoint.sh"]


##################################################
# Dev Image
##################################################

FROM base as dev

RUN apk info \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        xvfb \
        chromium \
        chromium-chromedriver\
        make \
        g++ \
        autoconf

##################################################
# Test Image
##################################################

FROM dev as test

# copy dotenv (to prevent laravel/dusk from failing during package discovery)
COPY ./src/.env.example ./.env

# copy application
COPY ./src ./

# install composer dependencies
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest

# install yarn dependencies
COPY ./src/package.json ./src/yarn.* ./
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile --no-progress

# build assets
RUN yarn production


##################################################
# Prod Image
##################################################

FROM base as prod

# copy application
COPY ./src ./

# install composer dependencies
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --no-dev --no-suggest

# install yarn dependencies and build assets
COPY ./src/package.json ./src/yarn.* ./
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile --no-progress && yarn production && rm -Rf ./node_modules

##################################################
# Console Image
##################################################

FROM prod as console

ARG USER_ROOT_NAME="ubuntu"
ARG USER_ROOT_UID="1000"
ARG USER_ROOT_GID="1000"

ENV USER_ROOT_NAME="${USER_ROOT_NAME}"
ENV USER_ROOT_UID="${USER_ROOT_UID}"
ENV USER_ROOT_GID="${USER_ROOT_GID}"

ENV AUTHORIZED_KEYS=""

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --upgrade --no-cache \
        bash \
        bash-completion \
        openssh-server \
        openssh-client \
        openssh-server-pam \
        sudo \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /root/.ssh \
    && chmod 0700 /root/.ssh \
    && addgroup -g "${USER_ROOT_GID}" "${USER_ROOT_NAME}" \
    && adduser -s "/bin/bash" -h "/home/${USER_ROOT_NAME}" -D -u "${USER_ROOT_UID}" -G "${USER_ROOT_NAME}" "${USER_ROOT_NAME}" \
    && passwd -u "${USER_ROOT_NAME}" &>/dev/null || true \
    && mkdir -p "/home/${USER_ROOT_NAME}/.ssh" \
    && chmod -R 700 "/home/${USER_ROOT_NAME}" \
    && chown -R "${USER_ROOT_UID}"."${USER_ROOT_GID}" "/home/${USER_ROOT_NAME}" \
    && echo "${USER_ROOT_NAME} ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers \
    && cat /etc/sudoers

# add ssh server config
RUN rm -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config

COPY .docker/app/openssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY .docker/app/openssh/create_bashrc.php /home/www-data/
COPY .docker/app/run-console.sh /home/www-data/run-console.sh

RUN chmod +x /home/www-data/run-console.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/www-data/create_bashrc.php


##################################################
# Local Dev Image
##################################################

FROM dev as local

RUN apk add --update linux-headers

RUN pecl install xdebug \
 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
 && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.idekey=DOCKER" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.log_level=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

Comment: You're trying hard to hide the important beginning of the Dockerfile, you should perhaps explain why you provide incomplete information when you ask for help. And have you tried if the build runs in a different network (a real one, not a locally namespaced one)? And why have composer and yarn in the prod stage? But that's not your actual issue. Are you behind a cooperate network that inserts self-signed certificates into the chain? Try to build the docker packages on a remote machine that does not have this security issue and contact your network administration.